# How to add a new shipping charges in rupees in PrestaShop?

Tags: php, content-management-system, e-commerce, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

**Hai There,**

Can anyone help me to solve **PrestaShop shipping** issue

My question:
if i purchased below Rs:250.00, automatically shipping charges will be added Rs:50 otherwise not added the shipping charge...

**Example:**

**Purchased:** Rs:50

**Shipping charge:** Rs:50

---

**Example 2:**

**Purchased:** Rs:200

**Shipping charge:** Rs:50

---

**Example 3:**

**Purchased:** Rs:250

**Shipping charge:** Free

Comment: please show your current code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution:

Basically, this is what you want to do.

**1)Shipping>Carriers>Add New >**
 Name it for example **(Free Ship over Rs.250)** it and assign it to the Zone you want with a checkmark ,Next make sure that the Out-Of Range Behavior is **set to Disable Carrier**.

**2)**Now Add New for another Carrier and name it for example **(Flat rate Under Rs.250)** with the same conditions as the first.

**3)** Next, you want to set up the weight and price ranges for these two carriers.

Go to **Shipping>Price Ranges>Add new**

You would need to do a Price Range for **Rs.250 to 1000000 for the Free Shipping Carrier** and **0 to  Rs.249 for the Flat Rate Carrier**
You also need to make weight ranges in **Shipping>Weight** Ranges even though they don't really matter. You can Add both of them and make the range of 0-100000 lbs

**4)**Go to **Shipping>Shipping** and make sure everything under the **"Handling"** section is set to "0". Under Billing, make sure it is According to Total Price

**5)** At **Shipping>Shipping** you see at the bottom (Fees by carrier, geographical zone and ranges).

On the Drop down select one of the carriers you just created. Lets do Free Shipping over $69, you should see  with the Range of  Rs.250 to 1000000.... Set that price to "0.00" (it should be that by default)

Next, find the Flat Rate Shipping on the Drop down. It should say 0 to  Rs.249 and make the fee  Rs.50.

I believe that is it! Make sure to disable all other carriers.

[For more help, watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwduTzFJmG0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwduTzFJmG0)